# how to copy array from resources to a local array android

Tags: android, xml, arrays, string

I have an array defined in my strings.xml file "names". I want the values in a local array in my program. how can i do this?

```
<string-array name="Names">

<item>  Adi </item>
<item>  John </item>
<item>  Adelaide    </item>
<item>  Alicante    </item>
</string-array name>
```

I want these values to be stored in a local array named item[]. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly modified from the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray):

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] item = res.getStringArray(R.array.Names);
```

Comment: thanks a lot dude.. it worked! It says u can accept an answer in 8 mins.. will do that in 8! :P

Answer (score 1):

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>

Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```